# C: Swap two nodes of a linked list

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, struct, nodes

I'm having trouble when there are only two nodes (not more) in a linked list that need to be swapped. When displaying this list, the swapping is done however only the last node is displayed.
this is part of the code that does the swapping:

```
typedef struct record
{   
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    char telephone[20];

}Record;

typedef struct node
{
    Record data;
    struct node *next;
}Node;

Node *head = NULL;

int cmpRecord(const Record* x, const Record* y) {   
    int cmp = strcmp(x->name, y->name);
    return (cmp > 0) - (cmp < 0);

}

void addRecord(Record x)
{

    Node *previousNode = NULL;
    Node *newNode;
    Node *n;

    newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));  
    newNode->data = x;  
    newNode->next = NULL;   

    if (head == NULL)  // The list is empty
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
```

Here is the logic for swapping the nodes

```
    else if (length == 1)
    {
        n = head;
        if (cmpRecord(&n->data.name, &newNode->data.name) > 0)
        {
            newNode->next = n;
            n = newNode;
            return;
        }       

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't update `head`, and the `cmpRecord` call parameters are off.  Try

```
else if (length == 1)
{
    n = head;
    if (cmpRecord(&(n->data), &(newNode->data)) > 0)  //<-- fix types
    {
        newNode->next = n;
        head = newNode; // <---- update head if the new record should be first
        return;
    }       

}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Worked perfectly now